# How to link mySQL with echarts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, charts

I am trying to link MySql with echarts to make my data to have a better visualisation. However, there is something wrong when I tried out this.

My SQL table:

[image]

there is two php file, one is to connect to mySQL (process.php), the other is to display the charts(testing.php).

The code for process.php is below:

```
<?php
header("Content-type=text/json;charset=UTF-8");

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "fypdb", "password123", "fyp");
$query = "SELECT * FROM study";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

class User{
    public $username;
    public $age;
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $row['name'];
    $user->age = $row['age'];
    $user->salary = $row['salary'];
    $data[] = $user;
}
mysqli_close($connect);

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

The code for testing.php is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <script src="js/echarts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='container' style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
        <script>
       var names = [], ages = [], salaries = [];

        function getusers() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                url: "process.php",
                data: {},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            names.push(result[i].username);
                            ages.push(result[i].age);
                            salaries.push(result[i].salary);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (errmsg) {
                    alert("Ajax data is wrong！" + errmsg);
                }
            });
            return names, ages;
        }

        // getting data from process.php
        getusers();

            var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("container"));



                    var option = {
                        tooltip: {
                            trigger: 'item',
                            formatter: "{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)"
                        },
                        legend: {
                            orient: 'vertical',
                            x: 'left',
                            data: names
                        },
                        series: [
                            {
                                name: 'name',
                                type: 'pie',
                                radius: ['50%', '70%'],
                                avoidLabelOverlap: false,
                                label: {
                                    normal: {
                                        show: false,
                                        position: 'center'
                                    },
                                    emphasis: {
                                        show: true,
                                        textStyle: {
                                            fontSize: '30',
                                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                labelLine: {
                                    normal: {
                                        show: false
                                    }
                                },
                                data: [

                                    {value: ages,name:names}


                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    };

            myChart.setOption(option);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS link is below (Full):

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/download.html

The output here is below which it should be in different color:
[image]

Comment: You should call chart.setOption in success callback.

Comment: Xhinvis, did you achieve to link mysql with echarts?